# How to join on columns that contain strings that aren't exact matches in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a simple table join on columns from two tables that are equivalent but not exact matches. For example, the row value in table A might be "Georgia Production" and the corresponding row value in table B might be "Georgia Independent Production Co".

I first tried a wild card in the join like this:

```
select BOLFlatFile.*, customers.City, customers.FEIN_Registration_No, customers.ST

 from BOLFlatFile

 Left Join Customers on (customers.Name Like '%'+BOLFlatFile.Customer+'%');
```

and this works great for 90% of the data. However, If the string in table A does not exactly appear in Table B, it returns `null`.

So back to the above example, if the value for table A were "Georgia Independent", it would work, but if it were "Georgia Production, it would not.

Comment: More than 1 sample will help here.

Comment: You need a Master Data Management solution, there is many on the market. Sample: https://profisee.com/master-data-management-what-why-how-who/

Answer (score 0):

This might be a complicated way of still being wrong, but this works with the sample I've mocked up.

The assumption is that because you are "wildcard searching" a string from one table to another, I am assuming that all of the words in the first table column appear in the second table column, which means by default that the second table column will always have a longer string in it than the first table column.

the second assumption is that there is a unique id on the first table, if there is not then you can create one by using the row_number function and ordering on your string column.

The approach below firstly creates some sample data (I've used tablea and tableb to represent your tables).

Then a dummy table is created to store the uniqueid for your first table and the string column.

Next a loop is invoked to iterate across the string in the dummy table and insert the unique id and the first section of the string followed by a space into the handler table which is what you will use to join the 2 target tables together.

The next section joins the first table to the handler table using the unique id and then joins the second table to the handler table on the key words longer than 3 letters (avoiding "the" "and" etc) joining back to the first table using the assumption that the string in table b is longer than table a (because you are looking for instances of each word in table a column in the corresponding column of table b hence the assumption).

```
declare @tablea table (
    id int identity(1,1),
    helptext nvarchar(50)
);


declare @tableb table (
    id int identity(1,1),
    helptext nvarchar(50)
);

insert @tablea (helptext)
values
('Text to find'),
('Georgia Production'),
('More to find');

insert @tableb (helptext)
values
('Georgia Independent Production'),
('More Text to Find'),
('something Completely different'),
('Text to find');

declare @stringtable table (
    id int,
    string nvarchar(50)
);

declare @stringmatch table (
    id int,
    stringmatch nvarchar(20)
);

insert @stringtable (id, string)
select id, helptext from @tablea;

update @stringtable set string = string + ' ';

while exists (select 1 from @stringtable)
    begin
        insert @stringmatch (id, stringmatch)
        select id, substring(string,1,charindex(' ',string)) from @stringtable;
        update @stringmatch set stringmatch = ltrim(rtrim(stringmatch));
        update @stringtable set string=replace(string, stringmatch, '') from @stringtable tb inner join @stringmatch ma
        on tb.id=ma.id and charindex(ma.stringmatch,tb.string)>0;
        update @stringtable set string=LTRIM(string);
        delete from @stringtable where string='' or string is null;
    end


        select a.*, b.* from @tablea a inner join @stringmatch m on a.id=m.id
        inner join @tableb b on CHARINDEX(m.stringmatch,b.helptext)>0 and len(b.helptext)>len(a.helptext);
```

Comment: That won't work here. `CHARINDEX('Georgia Production','Georgia Independent Production Co')` will return `0` (as it would with the parameters reversed).

Comment: If a location name appears reliably at the beginning of each column then you could substring the column up to a charindex of the first space and then charindex that in to the second column.

Comment: The problem is the location names are the same at the start. One has the word "Independent" between "Georgia" and "Production".

Comment: Tried this and it gave me the same output as my original code.

Comment: Please see edit and let me know if this has helped. I'm either spot on at this point or way off.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how complex you want to make this matching. There is various ways of matching these strings and some may work better than others. Below is an example of how you can split the names in your `BOLFlatFile` and `Customers` tables into separate words by using `string_split`.

The example below will match anything where all the words in the `BOLFlatFile` `customer` field are contained within the `customers` `name` field (note: it won't take into account ordering of the strings).

The code below will match the first two strings as expected, but not the last two sample strings.

```
CREATE TABLE BOLFlatFile
(
    [customer] NVARCHAR(500)
)

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    [name] NVARCHAR(500)
)


INSERT INTO Customers VALUES ('Georgia Independent Production Co')
INSERT INTO BOLFlatFile VALUES ('Georgia Production')
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES ('Test String 1')
INSERT INTO BOLFlatFile VALUES ('Test 1')
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES ('Test String 2')
INSERT INTO BOLFlatFile VALUES ('Test 3')

;with BOLFlatFileSplit
as
(
    SELECT *, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [customer]) as [WordsInName]
    FROM 
        BOLFlatFile
    CROSS APPLY 
        STRING_SPLIT([customer], ' ')
),
CustomerSplit as 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        Customers
    CROSS APPLY 
        STRING_SPLIT([name], ' ')
)
SELECT 
    a.Customer, 
    b.name
FROM 
    CustomerSplit b
INNER JOIN 
    BOLFlatFileSplit a
ON 
    a.value = b.value
GROUP BY 
    a.Customer, b.name
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = MAX([WordsInName])
```